# jQuery Accodion- Open Panel on Page Load from Site-Wide Navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-ui-accordion

I've been struggling with this for a few days, I've searched thoroughly for an answer to no end and haven't found anything yet. The script I am using is found here: http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html
And the project itself is here:
http://primefooddistributor.com/about.htm

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to have the side navigation link to the specific page (about.htm in this case) and open the appropriate panel of the accordion on page load. Here is the markup:

```
        <!-- ********************* Accordion  ********************* -->                    
                <ul id="acc1" class="accordion hidden" style="list-style-type:none">
                  <li>
                    <h2 class="header">Our Story</h2>

                    <div class="inner">
                      <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                        <li>
                          <h3 class="header" id="test">Stand Alone: PFD is a different kind of company.</h3>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p align="justify" class="bodytext"></p>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <h3 class="header">Ambassadors:</h3>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p align="justify"></p>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <h3 class="header">Tradition:</h3>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p align="justify">.</p>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <h2 class="header">Family Tree</h2>
                    <div class="inner">
                      <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                        <li>
                          <h3 class="header">Corporate Officers</h3>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p>
                                </p>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <h3 class="header">PFD Team</h3>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p>
                              </p>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="inner">
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <h2 class="header">Generations In Our Industry</h2>
                    <div class="inner">
                      <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                        <li>
                          <h3 class="header">The true definition of tradition ...</h3>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p>

                              </p>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="inner">
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="inner">
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <h2 class="header">My Story</h2>
                    <div class="inner">
                      <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                        <li>
                          <h3 class="header">The art of butchery requires two things:</h3>
                          <div class="inner">
                              <p>

                              </p>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="inner">
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="inner">
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul> <!-- end accordion  -->
```

And here is the jQuery Call:

```
    $(document).ready("html").addClass("js");
$.fn.accordion.defaults.container = false; 
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#acc1").accordion({
      el: ".h", 
      head: "h2, h3", 
      next: "div"
  });
  $("html").removeClass("js");
});
```

I am now trying to look at the URL hash passed from the navigation link, set the hash as a variable and use the variable to find the element by ID and add a class to the element. Here's what I have so far, but it's not working for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
      $(document).ready.getElementById(hash).addClass("open");
      // hash found 
  } else {
      // No hash found
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've worked on before:

http://jsfiddle.net/volterony/z333M/

I know you are citing this  block, but I think my example might do the job for you?

```
$(document).ready("html").addClass("js");
$.fn.accordion.defaults.container = false; 
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#acc1").accordion({
  el: ".h", 
  head: "h2, h3", 
  next: "div"
});
$("html").removeClass("js");
});
```

Hopefully its useful to you.

Volterony

Comment: I've also found something similar here http://jordanrodriguez.com/jquery-nested-accordion-menu

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into it now and get back to you soon.

Comment: Thanks again for the links, the accordion function is working fully right now on the site, it's the issue of linking to the specific accordion panels from external pages that I'm hung up on, I'm thinking the way to do it is to assign IDs to the "triggers" for the accordion then checking for the hash of the url on page load and opening that panel on page load, but I'm unsure how exactly to accomplish this.